# g++ and clang++ different behaviour inferring the template return type of a function

Tags: c++, templates, g++, type-inference, clang++

Another "who's right between g++ and clang++?" question for C++ standard gurus.

The following program

```
#include <iostream>

void foo (int v)
 { std::cout << "foo(), int version (" << v << ')' << std::endl; }

void foo (double v)
 { std::cout << "foo(), double version (" << v << ')' << std::endl; }

template <typename T, typename R>
void bar (T v, R(*fn)(T))
 { fn(v); }

int main ()
 { bar(1, foo); }
```

compile and run with g++ (6.3.0, but also with 8.0.0 according Wandbox) but compiling it with clang++ (3.9.1, but also with 6.0.0 according Wandbox) I get the following error

```
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:29:4: error: no matching function for call to 'bar'
 { bar(1, foo); }
   ^~~
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:25:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't
      infer template argument 'R'
void bar (T v, R(*fn)(T))
     ^
1 error generated.
```

As usual the question is: who's right? g++ or clang++?

Comment: The return type is not part of the function signature. Still it seems counter intuitive. I would use std:: function, so lambdas and functors can be used here as well.

Comment: `foo` would be ambiguous until `T` is fixed. Once `T` is fixed, `R` should be able to be deduced, but I think deduction is done in one pass.

Comment: @kamikaze Non capturing lambdas can already be passed. Having said that, using a template parameter instead is even better.

Comment: The fact that with `void bar (R(*fn)(T), T v)` both fail to compile make me thing that clang is right.

Comment: clang is right. overload resolution comes after template deduction. gcc is being too eager.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is correct, but for a subtle reason: an overload set is allowed during template deduction, but [deduction on that one argument](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#6.2) must be able to select one of them for anything to be deduced.  (If zero match, the overall deduction fails; if more than one does, deduction ignores that argument.)  Here, both `foo`s match `R(*fn)(T)`, so `R` cannot be deduced from that argument (even though they would both agree on it), and thus not at all.